# Playing wav files in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I have been having a few issues with wav files not playing lately, I am using code that I wrote two years ago (tweaked for ARC) and I was just curious if I am doing this the best way given that iOS has changed considerably since then?

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *buttonAudioPlayer;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize buttonAudioPlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:@"buttonClick_002" ofType:@"wav"]];
    [self setButtonAudioPlayer:[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error]];
    [buttonAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed ...");
    [[self buttonAudioPlayer] play];
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the simulator or on the device? Because in the simulator the file names aren't case-sensitive, but on the device they are. Other than that, I can't think why they might not be playing.

Comment: Thanks James, I have had  a good look at this and I think it might be something to do with the version of the SDK I am using.